# 歩道 vs 舗装 when meant part of road for people to walk (sidewalk, pavement, footpath)

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

As I understand 道 [michi] means any road or street, where people can walk and cars may drive.

But when we mean that part of road which was build to be used only by people to walk: sidewalk, pavement, footpath

1) Which word is better to use 歩道 [hodo:] vs 舗装 [hoso:]?
Are they full synonyms or they have some tiny difference in meaning?

2) Is there on SE question+answer like this [What is the difference between 市, 都市, 都会 and 市街](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/48973/) but on road/way/track/street/sidewak/boulevard/avenue/highway topic. Like a set of words with differeneces at meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

歩道 is a path made for walking. A sidewalk or foot path.

舗装 does not mean a path made for walking. It is the surface of a road. In the form 舗装する it can be a verb that means to pave a road.

Perhaps the confusion is coming from the fact that 舗装 can be translated into English as "pavement," and in British English "pavement" can mean "a path made for walking." But that is not the meaning of pavement that is intended here.